# How does COUNT behave when cross joins are involved in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with counting the number of results of one of my queries that uses cross join.

The data-gathering query is

```
SELECT CF.*, C.Type AS Ctype, C.Resp AS Resp 
FROM Campaigns C, CampaignEntities CF 
WHERE C.clientId = '10' AND LOWER(C.Resp) in ('resp1','resp2','resp3')
ORDER BY entityCode DESC
```

and it properly returns the rows that fit the criteria.

However, when changing it to get the number of rows that fit:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as RowNr 
FROM Campaigns C, CampaignEntities CF 
WHERE C.clientId = '10' AND LOWER(C.Resp) in ('resp1','resp2','resp3')
ORDER BY entityCode DESC
```

I get numbers in the millions (basically the result of the join without any of the WHERE conditions applied).

Any idea why it's behaving like this or how I can possibly get the right number?

Comment: Can't you just use you api's num_rows() method on the first query?

Comment: Still that doesn't explain why it is showing this behaviour. In fact on my box it doesn't. So maybe you should create a reduced test case with sample data.

Comment: You'll be getting something along the lines of COUNT(C.*) x COUNT(CF.*) because you're not joining or filtering the two tables at all.

Comment: @joocer I'm doing the exact same thing with many different tables and it works as you'd expect. Still can't figure out why it doesn't in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT COUNT(C.clientId) as RowNr
```

instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as RowNr
```

since `count(*)` counts even `null` rows

Comment: This still doesn't work. However, i'm gonna use mysql_num_rows to get the numbers. Can't afford the time to look into it.